# Creating a sliding panel using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate a sliding panel from this website http://12dishes.com/ using flexbox. I can't seem to create the slides in absolute positioning the whole layout disappear I'm not sure whats cause this?

Here what I've done so far:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
}
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section id="slider">
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="slider">
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: this whole question + answer is a perfect case for Stack Snippets: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements with `position: absolute` are removed from the document flow. This means they don't take up any space. Hence, the container has "nothing" inside and completely collapses.

To compensate for this behavior, try specifying a height for the container.

For example, add this to your code:

```
.wrapper { height: 80vh; }
```

Revised code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
}
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section id="slider">
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 1</h2>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section id="slider">
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="slide">
      <h2>Slide 2</h2>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```